# Pass multiple values through ActionLink or Submit button in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a scaffold list type table in my view. Above to the table, I have two checkboxes also. When I click on `Edit` link I need to pass the selected `Id` as well as the `CheckBoxes'` value also.

I can use `ActionLink` to pass the primary key value like

```
@Html.ActionLink("Action","Controller", new { id=@item.Id })
```

I can get the `CheckBoxes` Value by wrapping them into a `Html.Beginform` like,

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Action","Controller",FormMethod="Post"){
<input type="checkbox" name="Check" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Check" value="2" />

-- table

<input type="Submit" value="Edit"/>
```

and in my controller, I can handle this like

```
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult Edit(IEnumerable<string> check)
{ }
```

Here, I need to get both the `Primary key value` as well as `Checkboxes' value`, I tried in these two ways, and I could get any one of these only. Can anyone help me to get both the values? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include id in the action parameter. Like

```
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult Edit(IEnumerable<string> check, int id)
{ }
```

Also, you will need to post the form using a submit button not the action link.
So, for sending the id, you will need to put it in a hidden field and it will automatically be sent on post.

Make sure you name the hidden field the same as the parameter name i.e. "id".

**Edit**
Do like this:
Take a hidden field in form: like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hf" value="TEst" name="hid" />
```

Then take a edit button in each row and make it call a javascript function. Like below:

```
<button type="button" onclick="clickfunc(@item.UniqueId)">Edit</button>
```

Next Come in Javascript and set hidden field and then do a form submit. Like below:

```
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function clickfunc(id) {
        $("#hf").val(id);
        $('form').submit();
    }
    </script>
}
```

Now you get the values in your controller action. In my example it looks like:

```
public ActionResult EditTry(string hid)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, nice idea. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Possibly you can use JavaScript to fetch the values of checkboxes and id and then manually hit the action.

Comment: I placed a hidden field right next to the `Edit` button, its giving me the same `Id(first row's value)` in all the places.

Answer (score 1):

You will get selected value in "check" string

To get the name type jquery on submit button click and store it in hidden field and access the hidden field from form collection

```
       var getval = $("#Check option:selected").text();
            $("#hdnText").val(getval);
```

This is controller Code:

```
 [HttpPost]
        Public ActionResult Edit(string check, FormCollection collection)
            {
            string strText = collection["hdnText"].ToString();
            string strValue = check;
            }
```

Comment: How can I get the `Id(row)` value?